# I can't write 'Hello!' at the beggining of the question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting

I hope that I could find some help with the problem that I described with the title of this post. I forgot to write it when I first posted it and than when I edited few stuff I tried to add a 'Hello!', but it didn't work. Here is the link to my question:

[Checking my understanding of the process of developing function into power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162217/checking-my-understanding-of-the-process-of-developing-function-into-power-serie)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: These "hello"s are edited out because when your question shows up on the front page, only the beginning of what you wrote appears, and people decide whether they want to click and actually read everything just from those couple of lines. So in this sense, "hello" is a waste of space that will not get you more views. No one will think you're being impolite by not saying "hello", it's just how we roll here.

Comment: See a related question in MO Meta ... https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2543/disappearing-hi/2545#2545

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not supposed to write a greeting at the start of the question. There is a script in place that removes certain common forms of greetings (or at least what appears to be like one, there are rare false positives).

Of course there are ways to fool the script, but you should not.

Comment: I wrote maybe around 20 posts before this one and I always put 'Hello!' at the beggining and it was always displayed. I didn't know that it was against the rules. I am sorry. I just wanted to be polite as much as I can.

Comment: It's not a big deal. If you check in only one of your posts a "hello" persists, and there it is not at the start. Most of that was likely autoremoved.

Comment: OK! Thank you for clarification.